# postgresql get weekly average of cases with daily data

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called Table1. I am trying to get the weekly average, but I only have daily data. My table contains the following attributes: caseID, date, status and some other (irrelevant) attributes. With the following query, I made the following table which comes close to what I want:

However, I would like to add a average per week of the number of cases. I have look everywhere, but I am not sure how to include that. Has anybody any clues for how to add that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on @luuk's answer...

```
SELECT 
  date,
  COUNT(id) as countcase,
  EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date) AS weeknbr, 
  AVG(COUNT(id)) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date)) as weeklyavg
FROM table1
GROUP BY date, weeknbr
ORDER BY date, weeknbr
```

This is possible as the Aggregation / GROUP BY is applied before the window/analytic function.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  date, 
  countcase, 
  extract(week from date) as weeknbr, 
  avg(countcase) over (partition by extract(week from date)) as weeklyavg
from table1;
```

Comment: The only problem is that I create countcase in the query (it is not in the original table)... How do I get around that?

Comment: replace `countcase` with `count(id)` to match the query given in your question.

Comment: I understand that, but how does that work for calculating the average? Because it gives an error since countcase is not in the table.

Comment: It cannot give an error on `countcase`, because you replaced that with `count(id)` ?

Comment: Sorry, totally my bad... You are totally right! I works now!